# What is an Electronic Word™?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

For certain integers, there exist some corresponding Electronic Words™. Examples and non-examples include:

| Number | Electronic Words™ | Not Electronic Words™ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CHALK | BLACKBOARD |
| 0 | CABLE | WIRE |
| 1 | WRONG | CORRECT |
| 1 | BORON | CARBON |
| 2 | DEN | LAIR |
| 2 | DRY | WET |
| 3 | BANGER | SAUSAGE |
| 3 | LONGER | SHORTER |
| 4 | SLOWLY | QUICKLY |
| 4 | LOVELY | HATED |
| 5 | ENTER | EXIT |
| 5 | GENIE | DJINN |
| 6 | FUEL | EMPTY |
| 6 | TUBE | UNDERGROUND |
| 7 | TOILET | RESTROOM |
| 7 | MOTIVE | MOTIF |
| 8 | ARMY | NAVY |
| 8 | YANG | YIN |
| 9 | EIGHT | NINE |
| 9 | TWICE | THRICE |

CSV Version:

```
Number, Electronic Words™, Not Electronic Words™
0, CHALK, BLACKBOARD
0, CABLE, WIRE
1, WRONG, CORRECT
1, BORON, CARBON
2, DEN, LAIR
2, DRY, WET
3, BANGER, SAUSAGE
3, LONGER, SHORTER
4, SLOWLY, QUICKLY
4, LOVELY, HATED
5, ENTER, EXIT
5, GENIE, DJINN
6, FUEL, EMPTY
6, TUBE, UNDERGROUND
7, TOILET, RESTROOM
7, MOTIVE, MOTIF
8, ARMY, NAVY
8, YANG, YIN
9, EIGHT, NINE
9, TWICE, THRICE
```

What is the criterion to be an Electronic Word™?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a particular integer, an Electronic Word is a word which is...

> ...an anagram of the corresponding **[electronic resistor colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code)** *with a single letter changed*.
>
>  These integer-colour pairs are: 0 BLACK, 1 BROWN, 2 RED, 3 ORANGE, 4 YELLOW, 5 GREEN, 6 BLUE, 7 VIOLET, 8 GRAY, 9 WHITE.
>
>  [image: Resistor colours]

This can be seen like so:

> 0 BLACK = C[H]ALK, CABL[E]
>  1 BROWN = WRON[G], BOR[O]N
>  2 RED = DE[N], DR[Y]
>  3 ORANGE = [B]ANGER, [L]ONGER
>  4 YELLOW = [S]LOWLY, LO[V]ELY
>  5 GREEN = EN[T]ER, GEN[I]E
>  6 BLUE = [F]UEL, [T]UBE
>  7 VIOLET = [T]OILET, [M]OTIVE
>  8 GRAY = AR[M]Y, YA[N]G
>  9 WHITE = EI[G]HT, TWI[C]E
>
>  None of the counter-examples share this characteristic.